# Reaching connected tables with constraints same way linq/entity does it with .ToList(), just in clean Sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm sorry if my question is not well explained.
Been wondering if it is possible to reach for example connected table with foreign key with sql instead of using linq.
Maybe I will give an example.

Lets say I have two tables `Customers` and `Towns` with fk constraint from Towns table.
Now with linq to take both things at the same time I can just do that

```
using(DbContext db = new DbContext()){
    var customers = db.customers.ToList();

    //Then I can reach easy colums of towns just like that
    List<string> lt = new List<string>();
    foreach(var item in customers){
       lt.add(item.customers.towns.nameofthetown.ToString());
    }
}
```

The questions is, how to do that in normal SqlReader? Or is it something only you can do with linq/entity

Ok here are the classes for example case

```
public class Customers{
     public int ID{get;set;}
     public string Name{get;set;}
     pulic string Surname{ get;set}
}
public class Towns{
     public int ID{get;set;}
     public string NameOfTheTown{get;set}
     public int FkID{get;set;}
}
```

Now.. Customes is a parent table, Towns is a child.
How with use of clean sql (merge?) both of those tables in one list - List, just how I did in in example above with linq

I want the same effect as this `item.customers.towns.nameofthetown.ToString()` without using linq

Comment: are you wanting to write a sql query that does a join..? perhaps you can look at using an application like linqpad that can take the linq and transform it into normal sql or just write the sql query if you know the key you need to join on..

Comment: @MethodMan The thing is with inner join that one I do SqlReader I can' put it(or I just don't know how) two different tables two list that is in our case a List<Customers>, I would have to put things that has been inner joined from Towns to its own table instead of having it in one table like linq does it and I want to know if it is possible to do that with normal Sql without using Linq/entity

Comment: why can't you join 2 tables using a single SqlReader..? it's just a sql query are you familiar with how to write joins

Comment: You can easily answer your own question by examining the T-SQL generated by your Entity Framework LINQ query.

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to achieve is clear. The line where you add the Towns class is not very clear. item is a Customer. Why does it have a customers property?

Comment: @MethodMan Yeah, I'm familiar with joins just do not really know how to really make those two tables(one that is joined) into one table as example above

Comment: you need to word your question better.. because I read your question as you do not want to use Linq you would need to create the query in our EF code

Comment: @Harugawa please post your data models (just the entity classes relevant to your sample code) so I can help explain exactly what is going on to you

Comment: @MethodMan Sorry for me being bad at explaining, not my native language. Simplier saying . I want to reach result of what you can do with linq's ToList() of Parent table and get within it Childs tables that are constraint... but without any linq/entity, just in normal clean Sql

Comment: ok then you can write a query or stored procedure and execute that code and return the results ..

Comment: @Jakotheshadows edited post with models

Comment: @Harugawa are you sure those are correct and complete? There are no virtual properties on your models? Are these code-first or database first?

Answer (score 0):

```
var customers = db.customers.ToList();
```

This line loads the whole customers table into memory, which is done with

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
```

---

```
foreach(var item in customers){
   lt.add(item.customers.towns.nameofthetown.ToString());
}
```

This loop loads the related town row for the customer in each iteration, which is done with:

```
SELECT nameofthetown FROM town WHERE fkId = @customerId
```

Note: It is bad performance to roundtrip the database for each iteration of the loop.